# Is there a way to graphically add two curves in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, graphics, plot

Lets say I have a sine curve and a cosine curve. Is there any way to add them graphically? Rather than doing sin + cos?
I'm plotting things that are functions of different variables (lets say one curve takes x-values from an array of integers and the other from an array of irrational numbers), so I don't know how else to add them.

Comment: Hard to know what "adding them graphically" means.  I think you want to pick a set of common independent variables, evaluate the two functions at those points, and add the values.  You may have to do some interpolation to be able to evaluate both at a common independent variable value.

Comment: Is interpolation not an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want to plot `y1 = f1(x1)` and `y2 = f2(x2)` you could do this

```
X = union(x1, x2);
Y1 = interp1(x1, y1, X);
Y2 = interp1(x2, y2, X);
Y = Y1 + Y2;
plot(X, Y)
```

So to see this in action

```
x1 = 2 * pi * rand(50, 1);
x2 = 2 * pi * rand(50, 1);
y1 = cos(x1).^2;
y2 = sin(x2).^2;
X = union(x1, x2);
Y1 = interp1(x1, y1, X);
Y2 = interp1(x2, y2, X);
Y = Y1 + Y2;
plot(X, Y)
```